# how does this checks surrounding cells in a 2D array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to write a battleship game in ruby. I came across a code snippet that I think I grasp, but was hoping you all could maybe offer some clarification. The `[-1,0,1]` is what is throwing me. This is to check a 2D array. Thank you for your help as always.

```
def neighbors
  @neighbors ||= [-1, 0, 1].repeated_permutation(2).map do |dx, dy|
    @grid[x + dx, y + dy] unless dx.zero? && dy.zero?
  end.compact
end
```

I think I may have figured it out finally. The `repeated_permutation(2)` takes to of the values in the `[-1,0,1]` to search around the "cell" in question.

Comment: edited question to reflect the more pressing matter I'm looking for clarification on. I somewhat understand the `||=` was asking in the context of this snippet. But the part I really have a hard time grasping is the `[-1,0,1]`.

Comment: The paragraph you added (at the end) could be a comment, but your question should not also contain what amounts to an answer.

Comment: That snippet looks like it was written by someone who just discovered the method `Array#repeated_combination`. Wouldn't it be simpler and clearer to write `(@neighbors ||= [[-1,-1], [-1,0], [-1,1], [0,-1], [0,1], [1,-1], [1,0], [1,1]]).map { |dx, dy| @grid[x + dx, y + dy] }.compact`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `||=` means is if `@neighbors` responds to a `nil` (`NilClass`) object type or `false` (`FalseClass`) object value, it will take the value which you're assigning in the right side, that's to say the result of:

```
[-1, 0, 1].repeated_permutation(2).map do |dx, dy|
  @grid[x + dx, y + dy] unless dx.zero? && dy.zero?
end.compact
```

To use `||=` is like to use `x || x = a` or maybe `x = a unless x`, but in the Ruby way to be simple to read, simple to understand, simple to work with.

And what the `[-1, 0, 1].repeated_permutation(2).map` is trying to do is to map the result of a `repeated_permutation` over the `[-1, 0, 1]` array and to take the first and second value within the permutation, and to set your `@grid` variable probably (because I can't say what's `@grid`) as a range starting in the sum of `dx` plus `x` and then `dy` plus `y` unless the value of `dx` and `dy` are `0` at the same time (`&&`). Then `compact` the "mapped" result.

You might want to see [Array#repeated_permutation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/repeated_permutation) and [Array#permutation](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/permutation)

Comment: I've updated with an approximation of the `[-1, 0, 1].repeated_permutation(2).map ... compact` explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty permutations are like minor changes to a series of numbers ([link to more indepth])[1](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/probability/permutations-repeated-items.php).  What you're looking at is the array with being altered by the `.repeated_permutations` to find all options for each value & the results then being added to the original x & y coords...

The ||= & the unless parts are just checks to ensure the code doesn't run on 0's ...